# Getting a NPE with .add for a HashSet

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashset

I was starting to play around with HashSets in Java (I'm a beginner) and wanted to code a small little program which adds books.

```
public class HashSets
{
    private HashSet<String> books;

    public HashSets()
    {
        HashSet<String> books = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void addBook(String book)
    {
        books.add(book);
    }
}
```

But, and I don't understand why, I'm always getting a NPE with "books.add(book);". Apparently, the HashSet books is null, but I don't see why it should be. I don't get the exception when initialise the HashSet directly in the method "addBook".

Could someone maybe explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You are correct, `books` is `null`.  In your constructor you create a *local* variable called `books` that is hiding the class variable, which you never set.

Comment: In the constructor, use `this.books = new HashSet<>();`

Comment: @azurefrog Could you maybe elaborate? I assumed that by using `books`, which is a global variable, I'd just be initialising it in the constructor? I mean, you are right, of course - it works now - but I'm just curious!

Comment: `this.books` refers to the class variable, `books` implicitly refers to the class variable as well, but `HashSet<String> books` declares a brand new, local, variable of type `HashSet<String>`, also called `books`.

Comment: Thanks! Think I got it now!